# LINQ RemoveAll where property isn't working

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a **Module** Object and a property of Module is `Scenes`.

Scenes is a List;

I wanted to remove all Scenes where the name is `old_filename` (`String`).

I have implemented the code below but it isnt working and I think I might be close.

```
Module
    +Scenes = List<Scene>

Scene
    +Name (String)
```

LINQ

```
    mod.Scenes.RemoveAll(x=> !mod.Scenes.Any(y=>y.Name== old_filename ));
```

Comment: `RemoveAll` not a `LINQ`, it [List<T>.RemoveAll Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/wdka673a(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 5):

You appear to be looking up the same list inside your `RemoveAll` condition. Assuming you want to remove any `Scene` which has it's `Name` property set to `old_filename`, all you need to do is

```
 mod.Scenes.RemoveAll(x => x.Name == old_filename);
```

Comment: Ok ill try, I removed the NOT operator in my sample now everything deletes!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one:

```
mod.Scenes.RemoveAll(x=> x.Name==old_filename);
```